# JSON-formatted extract-document-data options node throws "unbalanced pairs" error when using multiple extract-paths

Tags: json, marklogic

MarkLogic REST Client API's default search endpoint results in server error when using a query options node that contains more than one extract-path even though the request is successful when either extract-path is used individually within extract-document-data:

```
{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":500, "status":"Internal Server Error", "messageCode":"RESTAPI-INTERNALERROR", "message":"RESTAPI-INTERNALERROR: (err:FOER0000) Internal error:  JSON build, unbalanced pairs: "}}
```

The offending paths:

```
<extract-path xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:FO="http://founders.archives.gov/">/tei:text/FO:metadata/FO:ProjectCode</extract-path>

<extract-path xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:FO="http://founders.archives.gov/">/tei:text/FO:metadata/FO:ShortProjectTitle</extract-path>
```

Only occurs when the format is JSON--XML format behaves as expected. This error can be reproduced across disparate datasets.

The entire options node:

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <search-option>unfiltered</search-option>
  <quality-weight>0</quality-weight>
  <page-length>10</page-length>
  <extract-document-data selected="include">
    <extract-path xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:FO="http://founders.archives.gov/">/tei:text/FO:metadata/FO:ProjectCode</extract-path>
    <extract-path xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:FO="http://founders.archives.gov/">/tei:text/FO:metadata/FO:ShortProjectTitle</extract-path>
  </extract-document-data>
</options>
```

I would simply extract the parent element FO:metadata; however, that returns a string, indicating a dependency on a parsing library (does it not?) which I would rather avoid if possible.

Any suggested workarounds are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your JSON search options?

Comment: Sure. These particular query options are in XML--it's very brief, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known bug with the inline response that should be fixed in 8.0-3.

In the interim, it should work to get the extracted fragments either as XML or as a multiplepart/mixed response (which, if the source documents are XML would also be XML).

Comment: I installed the maintenance release and can verify that bug #33648 is indeed fixed in 8.0-3!

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.